# Loading/saving .mat file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, save, load

I'm trying to load/save some .mat files using this code:

```
load('TensorMat/A_weekday.mat');
load('TensorMat/B.mat');
load('TensorMat/C_weekday.mat');
load('TensorMat/D_weekday.mat');
load('TensorMat/MAX_weekday.mat');
```

Which works fine.

However, when I try to do this:

```
save('TensorMat/P_weekday.mat', 'P');
```

I got a message saying that:

> Error using save
>
> Cannot create 'P_weekend.mat' because 'TensorMat' does not exist.

So far I have no idea why I can load for a directory but can't save on the same directory.

Both loading/saving codes are in the same .mat file.

Comment: Can you create a file in that folder using matlab? Might be an issue of permissions.

Comment: yup. syntax is valid. must be another issue.

Comment: Yes, I can, @Daniel.